# Sharing Intent Text Input

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

I want to the user to be able to share the *message* when the FAB is clicked. but what should I place `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, /* what should I put here*/);` here? I tried *message* but it does not work.

```
public class NoteDetailFragment extends Fragment {


public NoteDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_detail, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, /* what should I put here*/);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    });

    TextView title = (TextView)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewNoteTitle);
    TextView message = (TextView)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewNoteMessage);
    TextView thoughts = (TextView)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewNoteThoughts);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewNoteIcon);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

    title.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA));
    message.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA));
    thoughts.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_THOUGHTS_EXTRA));

    Note.Category noteCat = (Note.Category)intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA);
    icon.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(noteCat));


    return fragmentLayout;
}

}
```

Comment: You need to pass in a `String`, in plain text, that represents what you want to send. You need to decide for yourself where this string comes from, as you are the only one who knows what text you want to be sharing here.

Comment: oh so it's really impossible to send a text that the user typed?

Comment: No, that is very possible. However, we do not know where the user is entering this text. Your source code does not show signs of an `EditText`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra has two inputs. The first is a key identifying the string. The second is the message string.

Here is an example from the [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```